# R Shiny layout - how to add .co-xs-[] to columns?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I add .co-xs-[] to shiny layout?

For instance,

```
fluidRow(
  sidebarPanel(...
  ),
  mainPanel(...
  )
)
```

I get,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am after,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Or -

how can I insert `col-xs-4` into that column `<div class="col-xs-4">` **alongside** `col-sm-4`?

Comment: Looking at the source code in shiny https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/fc7208469d688d90044ae8a2f9b954c05b41a75f/R/bootstrap-layout.R  it looks like the "col-sm" is hardcoded in...

Comment: Thanks. how can I insert `col-xs-4` into that column `<div class="col-xs-4">` **alongside** `col-sm-4`?

Answer (score 4):

This might not be very clean, but I think you could just add the class you want as the `class` attribute of the column, and it will overwrite the one that shiny creates because its chronologically later.

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3, "a", class = "col-md-6"),
      column(3, "b", class = "col-md-6"),
      column(3, "c", class = "col-md-6"),
      column(3, "d", class = "col-md-6")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

  }
))
```

Each column will have both "col-xs-3" and "col-md-6" classes, but their actual width is 6, which makes me believe this can do what you want (yup, not clean.)

Comment: thanks. i tried that but then the form isn't there anymore. `sidebarPanel` comes with a form tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply do:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      div(class = "col-md-6", "a"),
      div(class = "col-md-6", "b"),
      div(class = "col-md-6", "c"),
      div(class = "col-md-6", "d")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

  }
))
```